# How to test a function that has side effects?

Tags: testing, functional-programming, side-effects

Given a function that does some operation on a database for instance.

In python, it would look like the following:

```
def dao_transfer(cnx, account_id1, account_id2, money):
   spam = cnx.execute('query 1', account_id1)
   egg = cnx.execute('query 2', account_2, spam)
   return egg
```

What I do in my unit tests is that I mock the `cnx` object, and only check
that `cnx.execute` is called and that `dao_transfer` returns the last mock return value of `cnx.execute`.

I have the feeling that this poor testing.

What Django does, is that it doesn't unittest functions that interacts with the database but instead, do what I call *integration* tests ie. you spawn a full database, you load it with some initial data, execute your side-effect powered function and check that the database is in the correct state.

I could do that, but I'd rather prefer unittests. Is there an approach to unit testing side effect function that doesn't rely on checking every single side effect function calls arguments?

Is there pure approach to IO that allows better unit testing?

Comment: Usually one eiter do integration test from predefined state or you do unit tests by mocking the side effects.